# Cloud Run Random restarts issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, scheduler, google-cloud-run

I'm building a monitoring application on GCP. At the moment I have 3 microservices, built with Spring Boot. For the monitoring part, I have a scheduler microservice, that creates a dynamic cron expression, based on the items coming from the request, exposed on the controller. It needs to be dynamic, because it monitors football matches.
All the microservices are currently deployed and running on GCP Cloud Run. Specifically for the Scheduler Application, I use this configuration, as the application must be always be alive and running otherwise the schedule is lost.

```
gcloud run deploy <service-name> --image=<image> --no-cpu-throttling --min-instances 1 --max-instances 1
```

The issue that I'm facing it's this. Despite having the instances (min and max) set to 1 and the cpu set to *no-throlling* the application keeps on restarting randomly.
[Cloud Run Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0vfj.png)

I've also tried looking on the metrics, but there is nothing wrong and the container instance, at 20:54 (the time that the application restarted) was 1.
[Instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2kY.png)
[Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAhhi.png)

Has anyone experienced this issue? If so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Run min instances is intended for reducing cold starts and not to keep a service running 24/7.

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances)

> if your service requires reduced latency and you want to limit the number of cold starts, you can change this default behavior by specifying a minimum number of container instances to be kept warm and ready to serve requests.

Using Minimum Instances to expect a service to always be up without any kind of disruption is a bad assumption since it is not the purpose of it. You should expect some [restarts from time to time](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances#restarts).

You can add more instances so the service "is always up" in case an instance is restarted but there is no guarantee that there will not be any restarts.

Then this is not an issue but working as intended.

Because of your use case, the best approach is to use a queue that triggers the service (like Pub/Sub or Cloud Tasks). With this you can reduce costs because CR will work only when needed instead of wasting CPU time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I tried to look for the cloud scheduler on GCP, but I didn't get if I can create dynamic scheduler for this. For my use case the scheduling isn't fixed (also for a matter of costs, and I don't want that my application runs all day for nothing). Maybe the Pub/Sub can help me, but I'm not sure. Do you have some example to provide?